# Clion linking fails

Tags: c++, clion

I have a header file

```
// Creates a new graph with n vertices and no edges
graph_t *graph_create(int n);
```

A .c file

```
graph_t *graph_create(int n)
{
    graph_t *g;
    int     i;

    //g = malloc(sizeof(graph_t));
    g->V = n;
    g->E = 0; 

    return g;
}
```

This is how my `CMakeLists.txt` looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Thesis)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp graph.h graph.c shared.h)
add_executable(Thesis ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I call `graph_t *g = graph_create(15);` from `main.cpp` and I get the following error saying that the method is undefined:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.2.4\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe"
>   --build C:\Users\Shiro.CLion12\system\cmake\generated\6e6ca233\6e6ca233\Debug
>   --target Thesis -- -j 8 Scanning dependencies of target Thesis [ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Thesis.dir/main.cpp.obj [ 66%] Building
>   C object CMakeFiles/Thesis.dir/graph.c.obj [100%] Linking CXX
>   executable Thesis.exe CMakeFiles\Thesis.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):
>   In function `main': C:/Users/Shiro/ClionProjects/Thesis/main.cpp:7:
>   undefined reference to`graph_create(int)' collect2.exe: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status CMakeFiles\Thesis.dir\build.make:121: recipe
>   for target 'Thesis.exe' failed mingw32-make.exe[3]:  [Thesis.exe]
>   Error 1 CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/Thesis.dir/all' failed CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for
>   target 'CMakeFiles/Thesis.dir/rule' failed Makefile:117: recipe for
>   target 'Thesis' failed mingw32-make.exe[2]: 
>   [CMakeFiles/Thesis.dir/all] Error 2 mingw32-make.exe[1]:
>   [CMakeFiles/Thesis.dir/rule] Error 2 mingw32-make.exe:  [Thesis]
>   Error 2

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: [See this answer as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574420/3747990)

Comment: @Niall Thanks, this also helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the function is defined in the `graph.c` C source file, the problem is because of [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

C++ uses mangled names to be able to handle things like overloading, and this is not needed for C. When you want to use a function from a C source file or C library, you need to tell the C++ compiler to not use mangled names, and this is done with the `extern "C"` construct, as in

```
extern "C" graph_t *graph_create(int n);
```

There's a problem with that though, and that is that the C compiler will not know what you mean by `extern "C"`, and it will complain. For this you need to use *conditional compilation* using the preprocessor, and check if the header file is being used by the C++ or the C compiler. This is done by checking for the existence of the `__cplusplus` macro:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
graph_t *graph_create(int n);
```

If you have multiple functions, then put them in a brace-enclose block:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

graph_t *graph_create(int n);
// More functions here...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}  // End of extern "C" block
#endif
```

Comment: Hmm, I was expecting an answer in the lines of, you need to chance X settings. But this definitely worked. So, I actually have to add `#ifdef __cplusplus  extern "C"  #endif` on every header file ? Will this create any problems with compatibility of any sort ? I mean is this a clean solution that people use ? I understand that this is a "problem" with C and C++ compilers being different, not the actual IDE, so this solution is used in all programs that are using C and C++ at the same time ?

Comment: @Shiro If you look at just about any C library you find on the world wide Internet, you will see this. It's the only way to go around the name-mangling problem. And it's completely safe and will only impact compilation time marginally (as in not measurable).

Comment: Well that's great news, and thanks for the amazing explanation in your answer about mangled names

Comment: Should I put the whole header file in those brackets ? or just the functions ? is there a real difference ?

Comment: @Shiro It doesn't matter, only functions and their prototypes will be affected. I've seen both styles.